# Encoded test script for IONCUBE

Tags: php, ioncube

I'm looking for an example script - or simple application - that would let me test if ioncube decoder works properly with php5.5 and additional modules (e.g. OPcache).

Every script I Found online and tried on my host encoded for php < 5.5. I do not own IonCube Encoder (and I don't plan to), but ATM i also don't have any encoded application :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download an evaluation of the ionCube software via http://ioncu.be/eev

If you avail yourself of the demo, you can produce test files to your heart's content yourself. Be sure to use ioncube_encoder55 on the command line or to select PHP 5.5 for the source language in project settings if using the GUI.

Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube